# Android Notification re-appears after being opened

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications

I am posting notifications everytime a new announcement is posted. I fetch announcements from Firebase so I call the notification function on `onChildAdded()`. I'm receiving notifications for every new announcement. However, if there isn't a new announcement, the latest announcement re-appears every once in a while even after opening it.

Notifications class:
    public class FirebaseBackgroundService extends Service {

```
private Firebase f = new Firebase("https://infotrack.firebaseio.com/infotrack/announcements");
Query queryAnnouncements = f.orderByChild("timeStamp").limitToLast(1);
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://infotrack.firebaseio.com/guests");
Firebase userRef = ref.child("users/"+ref.getAuth().getUid()+"/notifications");

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

            ChildEventListener handler = new ChildEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            final AnnouncementsList announcement = dataSnapshot.getValue(AnnouncementsList.class);
            Log.e("announcements", dataSnapshot.getKey());

            userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot notifSnapshot) {
                    Log.e("check", notifSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                    if (notifSnapshot != null) {
                    Notifications notif = notifSnapshot.getValue(Notifications.class);
                        if(!dataSnapshot.getKey().equals(notif.getAnnouncements())){
                            buildNotif("Announcement", announcement.getBody(), "New announcement from Infotrack");
                            userRef.child("announcements").setValue(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) { }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {}

    };

    queryAnnouncements.addChildEventListener(handler);
}

private void buildNotif(String body){
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    builder.setContentTitle("New Announcement")
            .setContentText(body)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 500, 1000, 0, 1000 })
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Announcements.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this,
                    0,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );

    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());

}
```

}

Broadcast Receiver:

```
public class StartFirebaseAtBoot extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    context.startService(new Intent(FirebaseBackgroundService.class.getName()));
}
```

}

Android Manifest:

```
<service
        android:name=".FirebaseBackgroundService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:process=":remote" >
    </service>

    <receiver android:name=".StartFirebaseAtBoot" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This line I placed in the onCreate() method of my MainActivity:
`startService(new Intent(this, FirebaseBackgroundService.class));`

Stacktrace:

```
    02-14 18:41:25.262 2446-2446/xyz.kimfeliciano.infotrack.infotrack:remote E/announcements: -KAUMTXlrOFvFaj20TNi
    02-14 18:41:25.282 2446-2446/xyz.kimfeliciano.infotrack.infotrack:remote E/check: {announcements=-KAUM5H34QI-VklVRGSQ, news=1}
    02-14 18:41:25.372 2446-2446/xyz.kimfeliciano.infotrack.infotrack:remote E/check: {announcements=-KAUMTXlrOFvFaj20TNi, news=1}
    02-14 18:41:25.382 2446-2446/xyz.kimfeliciano.infotrack.infotrack:remote E/check: {announcements=-KAUMTXlrOFvFaj20TNi, news=1}
    02-14 18:41:25.802 2446-2446/xyz.kimfeliciano.infotrack.infotrack:remote E/check: {announcements=-KAUM5H34QI-VklVRGSQ, news=1}
    02-14 18:41:25.812 2446-2446/xyz.kimfeliciano.infotrack.infotrack:remote E/check: {announcements=-KAUM5H34QI-VklVRGSQ, news=1}
    02-14 18:41:25.902 2446-2446/xyz.kimfeliciano.infotrack.infotrack:remote E/check: {announcements=-KAUMTXlrOFvFaj20TNi, news=1}
    02-14 18:41:25.902 2446-2446/xyz.kimfeliciano.infotrack.infotrack:remote E/check: {announcements=-KAUMTXlrOFvFaj20TNi, news=1}
    02-14 18:41:25.942 2446-2446/xyz.kimfeliciano.infotrack.infotrack:remote E/check: {announcements=-KAUM5H34QI-VklVRGSQ, news=1}
    02-14 18:41:25.942 2446-2446/xyz.kimfeliciano.infotrack.infotrack:remote E/check: {announcements=-KAUM5H34QI-VklVRGSQ, news=1}
    02-14 18:41:25.962 2446-2446/xyz.kimfeliciano.infotrack.infotrack:remote E/check: {announcements=-KAUMTXlrOFvFaj20TNi, news=1}
    02-14 18:41:25.972 2446-2446/xyz.kimfeliciano.infotrack.infotrack:remote E/check: {announcements=-KAUMTXlrOFvFaj20TNi, news=1}
    02-14 18:41:25.992 2446-2446/xyz.kimfeliciano.infotrack.infotrack:remote E/check: {announcements=-KAUM5H34QI-VklVRGSQ, news=1}
    02-14 18:41:25.992 2446-2446/xyz.kimfeliciano.infotrack.infotrack:remote E/check: {announcements=-KAUM5H34QI-VklVRGSQ, news=1}
    02-14 18:41:26.012 2446-2446/xyz.kimfeliciano.infotrack.infotrack:remote E/check: {announcements=-KAUMTXlrOFvFaj20TNi, news=1}
    02-14 18:41:26.032 2446-2446/xyz.kimfeliciano.infotrack.infotrack:remote E/check: {announcements=-KAUMTXlrOFvFaj20TNi, news=1}
    02-14 18:41:26.042 2446-2446/xyz.kimfeliciano.infotrack.infotrack:remote E/check: {announcements=-KAUM5H34QI-VklVRGSQ, news=1}
    02-14 18:41:26.052 2446-2446/xyz.kimfeliciano.infotrack.infotrack:remote E/check: {announcements=-KAUM5H34QI-VklVRGSQ, news=1}
    02-14 18:41:26.122 2446-2446/xyz.kimfeliciano.infotrack.infotrack:remote E/check: {announcements=-KAUMTXlrOFvFaj20TNi, news=1}
    02-14 18:41:26.132 2446-2446/xyz.kimfeliciano.infotrack.infotrack:remote E/check: {announcements=-KAUMTXlrOFvFaj20TNi, news=1}
    02-14 18:41:26.152 2446-2446/xyz.kimfeliciano.infotrack.infotrack:remote E/check: {announcements=-KAUM5H34QI-VklVRGSQ, news=1}
```

it goes on until this last line:

```
02-14 18:41:42.402 2446-2446/xyz.kimfeliciano.infotrack.infotrack:remote E/check: {announcements=-KAUMTXlrOFvFaj20TNi, news=1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the app connects to the server, Firebase will call `onChildAdded()` for each existing child at the location. So unless you delete the children, the number of `onChildAdded()` invocations will keep going up.

You have two options:

- remove the notification from the database after you've shown it to the user

  ```
  public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildKey) {
      AnnouncementsList announcement = snapshot.getValue(AnnouncementsList.class);
      buildNotif(announcement.getBody());
      snapshot.getRef().remove();
  }
  ```
- mark the notifications that the user has seen and skip those

Most applications go with the first option, since it automatically keeps the queue short.

Comment: My app displays the previous announcements so I cannot go with the first option and remove them. Abt the 2nd option, I thought I would create an array and add the marked announcements to it for each user. The thing is, I do not have a table/data for each user where I could save the marked announcements because my app doesn't require user authentication/registration. Suggestions?

Comment: If you need to track *per user* whether they've gotten a notification, you'll need some way to identify that user. If you don't want to require the user to sign in, consider using [anonymous authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/login/anonymous.html). But keep in mind that this means that if one person uses two devices, they'll get notified on each (since each device will have an anoynmous user with a different uid).

Comment: How come even when I'm not connected to the internet, the notification would re-appear after certain intervals?

Comment: It's impossible to be certain without an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But most likely the data is available in Firebase (memory or disk) cache. When you reattach a listener, the `child_added` events will fire again.

Comment: Following your advice, I used firebase anon authentication and list down the latest marked announcement under the user data. It's finally working, I 'm not experiencing repeats of the same announcement anymore. However, my logcat goes crazy whenever I post a new announcement. I updated my code above

Comment: You log an error for each `onChildAdded()`. So when you reattach the listener, it will log an error for each child. I'm not sure your check on `onChildAdded()` will work, so I recommend stepping through it in a debugger.

Comment: I always log as error so the text would appear in red. Anyway, I was wrong when I said I did not experience repeats. Apparently, my notification was blinking (alternately displaying what were on the "error" logs). How do I turn off the userRef listener once a value has been set already?